# Reduce spacing between two consecutive tables in a LaTeX paper

Tags: tables, spacing

I have an unwanted space between two successive tables in my paper. How can I remove it?

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
        \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-class rtm\textsubscript{c} input traces}
        \label{ClassTracesInput}
        \tabcolsep=2.5pt
        \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
            \hline   \textbf{System}
            & \textbf{T\textsubscript{c}(\#)} & \textbf{N\textsubscript{c}(\#)} &
            \textbf{U\textsubscript{c}(\#)}&
            \textbf{Total} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{c}(\%)} &
            \textbf{N\textsubscript{c}(\%)} & \textbf{U\textsubscript{c}(\%)}  \\ \hline
            \textbf{Chess} & 131 & 253 & 448 & \textbf{832} & 15.75 & 30.41 & 53.85 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Gantt} & 93 & 2483 & 9412 & \textbf{11988} & 0.78 & 20.71 & 78.51 \\
            \hline
            \textbf{iTrust} & 181 & 2743 & 21488 & \textbf{24412} & 0.74 & 11.24 & 88.02 \\
            \hline
            \textbf{JHotD.} & 98 & 1490 & 12335 & \textbf{13923} & 0.70 & 10.70 & 88.59 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-method rtm\textsubscript{m} Input Gold Standard}
        \label{GoldStandardInputCompleteness}
        \tabcolsep=2.5pt
        \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
            \hline   \textbf{System}
            & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m}(\#)} & \textbf{N\textsubscript{m}(\#)} &
            \textbf{U\textsubscript{m}(\#)}&
            \textbf{Total} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{m}(\%)} &
            \textbf{N\textsubscript{m}(\%)} & \textbf{U\textsubscript{m}(\%)}  \\ \hline
            \textbf{Chess} & 563 & 2389 & 3064 & \textbf{6016} & 9.36 & 39.71 & 50.93 \\ \hline
            \textbf{Gantt} & 343 & 23166 & 66725 & \textbf{90234} & 0.38 & 25.67 & 73.95 \\
            \hline
            \textbf{iTrust} & 307 & 7173 & 159562 & \textbf{167042} & 0.18 & 4.30 & 95.52 \\
            \hline
            \textbf{JHotD.} & 439 & 12219 & 124262 & \textbf{136920} & 0.32 & 8.92 & 90.76 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have an unwanted space between two successive tables in my paper, how can I remove it?

Just use a single `table` environment, with 2 `tabular` environments and 2 `\caption` and 2 `\label` statements. Depending on your personal preferences, use either `\bigskip` or `\bigskip\bigskip` to insert a bit of vertical whitespace between the tables.

```
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\centering
    \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-class rtm\textsubscript{c} input traces}
    \label{ClassTracesInput}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    % body of first tabular env.
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip % or \bigskip\bigskip

    \caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-method rtm\textsubscript{m} Input Gold Standard}
    \label{GoldStandardInputCompleteness}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    % body of second tabular env.
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

---

*Addendum*: Applying the suggest to use a single `table` environment, and further applying some streamlining to the appearance of the table, one might arrive at something like this:

[image]

Observe that I got rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, provided some more explicit structure to the header rows, and dropped all `\textbf` directives.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{lipsum,array,booktabs,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{3} % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht!]
\tabcolsep=0pt

\caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-class rtm\textsubscript{c} input traces}
\label{ClassTracesInput}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{r} @{}}
\toprule   
System & $T_c$ & $N_c$ & $U_c$ & Total & $T_c$ & $N_c$ & $U_c$ \\ 
& (\#) & (\#) & (\#) & & (\%) & (\%) & (\%)  \\
\midrule
Chess & 131 & 253 & 448 & 832 & 15.75 & 30.41 & 53.85 \\ 
Gantt & 93 & 2483 & 9412 & 11988 & 0.78 & 20.71 & 78.51 \\ 
iTrust & 181 & 2743 & 21488 & 24412 & 0.74 & 11.24 & 88.02\\ 
JHotD. & 98 & 1490 & 12335 & 13923 & 0.70 & 10.70 & 88.59 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip\medskip

\caption{Quantifying the requirement-to-method rtm\textsubscript{m} Input Gold Standard}
\label{GoldStandardInputCompleteness}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{r} @{}}
\toprule  
System & $T_m$ & $N_m$ & $U_m$ & Total & $T_m$ & $N_m$ & $U_m$ \\ 
& (\#) & (\#) & (\#) & & (\%) & (\%) & (\%)  \\
\midrule
Chess & 563 & 2389 & 3064 & 6016 & 9.36 & 39.71 & 50.93 \\ 
Gantt & 343 & 23166 & 66725 & 90234 & 0.38 & 25.67 & 73.95\\ 
iTrust& 307 & 7173 & 159562 & 167042 & 0.18 & 4.30 & 95.52\\ 
JHotD.& 439 & 12219 & 124262 & 136920 & 0.32 & 8.92 &90.76\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum % produce some filler text
\end{document}
```