# How can I set the distance between three consecutive tables in Latex?

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

I have three tables in my document in Latex and unwanted a lot of spaces are created between them. I can't figure out how to reduce these spaces.

[image]

I have also tried different suggestions such as [link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544845/reduce-spacing-between-two-consecutive-tables-in-a-latex-paper), [link2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46146/reduce-vertical-space-between-text-and-table-and-remove-table-indentation). Unfortunately, None of them solved the problem completely.

Also, I found this problem is because of the first settings of the `\documentclass[<options>]{cas-dc}`, which I have put along with the following packages, which are used in my document in Latex, in the following code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{subcaption}


%%%Author definitions
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
\tsc{EP}
\tsc{PMS}
\tsc{BEC}
\tsc{DE}
%%%


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, multirow}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4, tight-spacing=true, separate-uncertainty}

\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
    exponent-product={},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2,
    table-space-text-pre    = (,
    table-space-text-post   = ),
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=Plaintop, captionskip=0pt, capposition=top}

\let\sum\relax % To change the style of summation symbol
\DeclareSymbolFont{otherlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{otherlargesymbols}{"50}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}\sloppy
\justify

\title [mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}
rtydf

\maketitle


%\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{table*}[hbt!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.95pt}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.7\textwidth}
\captionsetup{width=.69\linewidth}
%\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
%\vspace*{2 mm}
%\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.3}
\caption{bbbb}\label{tbl:2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c *{7}{S} @{}}  % 1 'c' column, 4 'S' columns
\bottomrule
\multirow{2.5}{*}{}
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{C1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-8} & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {G}\\

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{90 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{90 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[hbt!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.95pt}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.7\textwidth}
\captionsetup{width=.69\linewidth}
%\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
%\vspace*{2 mm}
%\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.3}
\caption{ccc.}\label{tbl:2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c *{7}{S} @{}}  % 1 'c' column, 4 'S' columns
\bottomrule
\multirow{2.5}{*}{}
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{C1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-8} & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {G}\\

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{90 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{90 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[hbt!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.95pt}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.7\textwidth}
\captionsetup{width=.69\linewidth}
%\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
%\vspace*{2 mm}
%\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.3}
\caption{ddd}\label{tbl:2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c *{7}{S} @{}}  % 1 'c' column, 4 'S' columns
\bottomrule
\multirow{2.5}{*}{}
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{C1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-8} & {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {G}\\

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{9 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\bottomrule
\multirow{1.3}{*}{TTT:}\\
\midrule
AA & \num{8.12 \pm 3.5} & \num{1} & \num{1 \pm 7.91} &
\num{9 \pm 4.24} & \num{9 \pm 3.21} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{5 \pm 3.12}\\
BB & \num{2.1 \pm 4.52} & \num{7.69 \pm 10} & \num{21} &
\num{6 \pm 5.80} & \num{15 \pm 6.2} & \num{17} &
\num{10}\\
CC & \num{6.14 \pm 6.2} & \num{9.67 \pm 10.54} & \num{8.5 \pm 7.1} & \num{14.83 \pm 6.79} & \num{9.7 \pm 7.5} & \num{2.50 \pm 7.91} &
\num{13.75 \pm 3.95}\\
DD & \num{15.71 \pm 13.55} & \num{12 \pm 31.62} & \num{45} &
\num{12 \pm 1.62} & \num{90 \pm 31.62} & \num{0} &
\num{1.50 \pm 2.91}\\
%\bottomrule
\midrule

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I deleted the biblatex tag that you added but does not seem related.

Comment: Why did the "keep them in a single float" option not work?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `cas-dc` is intended for journal submission. If you are using it to submit an article to a Jornal you should *not* change the layout parameters. The whole point of a publisher supplied class is to remove choice from the author and enforce a consistent style.

However to answer the question as asked:

These are double column floats on a float page so they are spaced `\@dblfpsep` apart.

Adding

```
\makeatletter
\@dblfpsep=0pt
\makeatother
```

to your preamble sets this to 0pt and the tables have no space at all, set to a length that you prefer.

Comment: The length of election must be probably the default. It is a Elsevier class ...

Comment: @Fran well that's true: I hadn't noticed it was a journal class. I will add a big don't do this warning.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks. I have applied your suggestion,  but it couldn't solve my problem completely. The distance between table 1 and table 2 is ok, but table 3 is still far from these two tables. Also, there is an unwanted space between table 1 and the top of the page.

Comment: @Ellie this changes the spaces between floats on a float page (a page with just floats and no text) perhaps you have tables appearing on text page which use different parameters. Impossible to guess, also note that "don't do this" warning I added.

Comment: @Fran Yes, but these three tables don't have good position in my document.

Comment: @ David Carlisle: Yes, I have applied it on text pages (my original document).

Comment: @Ellie David has already explained the issue. You should care of a consistent   document structure, not of the final layout. This is a problem of the editor, not of the authors, In other words; if I were you I would not interfere with the editor's choices, for example, setting the style of the captions, as you also have done in the example.